# What does "?." (dot after questiion mark) mean in JS

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-2020

I stumbled  upon the  "?." syntax  in another SO question.  Something like this -

```
console.log(x?.y?.z);
```

What does it do?

Comment: How can you ask and answer in the same seconds?

Comment: @klediooo By ticking the "_Answer your own question_" checkbox at the bottom of the ["Ask a Question" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Yes - Thats what I did. First time though ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

It allows to use the property chaining without having to validate properties in each level. It short circuits property evaluation without raising exceptions - thus avoiding the "Cannot read X of undefined" error.

```js
let o = {p: {q: 'foo'}};


try {
  console.log('Trying to access the property x');
  console.log(o.x.y);
}
catch(e) {
  console.log('That was an error');
}


console.log('Trying to access the property x with Optional Chaining');

console.log(o?.x?.y);
```

---

**Optional chaining more use cases**

With function calls

> `let result = someInterface.customMethod?.();`

With expressions

> `let nestedProp = obj?.['prop' + 'Name'];`

With array elements

> `let arrayItem = arr?.[42];`

[ECMAScript Draft](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-OptionalExpression)

Comment: browser compatibility: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining